# FeedMe Node Attributes

Tags: plugin-feedme

I have the following XML:

```
<nodes>
    <node>
        <title>Test Org - Pleae Ignore</title>
        <logo>
            <enclosure url="https://www.mydomain.org/sites/default/files/louis%20xiv.jpg" length="71280" type="image/jpeg" />
        </logo>
    </node>
    <node>
        <title>Test Org - Pleae Ignore</title>
        <logo>
            <enclosure url="https://www.mydomain.org/sites/default/files/louis%20xiv.jpg" length="71280" type="image/jpeg" />
        </logo>
    </node>
    <node>
        <title>Test Org - Pleae Ignore</title>
        <logo>
            <enclosure url="https://www.mydomain.org/sites/default/files/louis%20xiv.jpg" length="71280" type="image/jpeg" />
        </logo>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

And the following template markup:

```
{% set params = {
    url: 'https://www.domain.org/xml-details?nid=12345',
    type: 'xml',
    element: 'node',
    cache: 60,
} %}

{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}
{% for node in feed %}
    {{ node.title }}
    {{ node.logo.enclosure.attributes.url }}
{% endear %}
```

`{{ node.title }}` displays fine, but `{{ node.logo.enclosure.attributes.url }}` displays nothing.

Based on other threads I've read, I've also tried `{{ node.logo.enclosure['@url'] }}`

Neither returns the value of the `url` attribute.

Any help getting this to work is appreciated.

EDIT: Using just `{{ node.logo }}` in the template outputs `<enclosure url="https://www.mydomain.org/sites/default/files/louis%20xiv.jpg" length="71280" type="image/jpeg" />`.

EDIT: Here's my `{{ dump(node) }}` output.

```
array(30) {
  ["recordId"]=>
  string(5) "19795"
  ["title"]=>
  string(22) "Robertson Blood Center"
  ["summary"]=>
  string(101) "<p>Volunteer- Donate blood. Your donation of life is used by wounded military at home and abroad.</p>"
  ["logo"]=>
  string(156) "<enclosure url="https://www.mydomain.org/sites/default/files/1959440_10152076927213038_3915913252856478361_n%5B1%5D_2.jpg" length="35608" type="image/jpeg" />"
}
```

Comment: You could dump the `{{ node.logo}}` to see if it contains the property enclosure and continue with that until you reach `attributes`

Comment: @RobinSchambach - I should have mentioned in the OP that `{{ node.logo }}` does, indeed, display the full `<enclosure />` element. So the content is there. I just can't get FeedMe to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax you're looking for is:

```
{{ node.logo.enclosure['@url'] }}
```

As a handy hint, you can use the following to inspect any element parsed by Feed Me to see how you can access it. Using `{{ dump(node.logo.enclosure) }}` for example, you can see an array with keys and values for you to access.

This is also outlined in the documentation - https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/feature-tour/using-in-your-templates#example-template-code

EDIT: Refer to full code below

```
{% set params = {
    url: 'http://feedme.craft.dev/stack.xml',
    type: 'xml',
    element: 'node',
} %}

{% for node in craft.feedme.feed(params) %}
    <pre>
        {{ dump(node) }}
    </pre>
{% endfor %}
```

Produces:

```
array(2) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(23) "Test Org - Pleae Ignore"
  ["logo"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["enclosure"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["@url"]=>
      string(60) "https://www.mydomain.org/sites/default/files/louis%20xiv.jpg"
      ["@length"]=>
      string(5) "71280"
      ["@type"]=>
      string(10) "image/jpeg"
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 2: Looking at your exact feed, I can see the issue. Your feed actually has HTML, which is interpreted as a string. For instance:

```
<logo>
    &lt;enclosure url="https://www.mydomain.com/1959440_10152076927213038_3915913252856478361_n%5B1%5D_2.jpg" length="35608" type="image/jpeg" /&gt;
</logo>
```

Notice how is your original example its assumed its all XML? In fact, the logo node contains HTML, which is just treated like a string.

Comment: You'll see in the OP I tried that syntax and got no output. I'll try the dump and see what happens.

Comment: Added code with full implementation of the array dump on my end.

Comment: I added `{{ dump(node.logo.enclosure) }}` and got an `unknown "dump" function` error.

Comment: Apparently I needed Dev Mode on. I added the dump output to my OP, which you'll see doesn't look like what you expected.

Comment: Without looking at your feed, its hard to tell, but there seems to be HTML directly in your feed, which is considered a string to Feed Me (it will parse the XML, but not the inner HTML). Maybe we'll follow up further via Slack? Username is @crawf

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. I didn't understand that previously because everything I viewed the XML feed in rendered the HTML, which made it _LOOK_ like a valid XML tag. But when I view the raw feed, I see now that the tag brackets are actually being stored as HTML entities. Thanks for the assist. I'll see if the data provider can modify how that is being output.